# R: How to obtain corresponding column of values?

Tags: r

Let's say I have three columns A, B, and C. I've taken a subset of A (say every other row), how do I obtain the corresponding values of those rows in C?

```
    A   B   C
1   a1  a1  c1
2   a2  b2  c2
3   a3  b3  c3
4   a4  b4  c4
```

I want:

```
     A   C
1   a1  c1
2   a3  c3
```

Note: using every other row for the subset in column A was just an example, I'm looking for a more general solution. That is, if I have a subset of the column A, how do I get the corresponding values in column C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can recycle the `TRUE/FALSE` as the row index to get alternating rows, and column names as column index to subset the dataset.

```
df1[c(TRUE, FALSE),c('A', 'C')]
#   A  C
#1 a1 c1
#3 a3 c3
```

If we want to subset the rows based on the values in 'A', create the row index based on 'A' and select the columns that we need to have in the expected output.

```
df1[df1$A %in% c('a1', 'a3'), c('A', 'C')]
```

If we are using `data.table` (convert the data.frame to data.table using `setDT`) , we can set the key column and then directly subset the rows by using the elements in the 'subA'.  For the column index, it is similar as above, but we need to use `with=FALSE`.  More info can be found at `?data.table`

```
library(data.table)
subA <- c('a1', 'a3')
setDT(df1, key='A')[subA, c('A', 'C'), with=FALSE]
#   A  C
#1: a1 c1
#2: a3 c3
```

Comment: Well, using every other row was only an example. I need a more abstract case. If I have a subset of values in column A, how do I get the corresponding values in column C?

Comment: so if I called my subset of column A `subA`, would I just do `df1[subA, c('A', 'C')]` ?

Comment: @AlanH It should be a numeric or logical index for subsetting the rows.

Comment: So how do I use subA then? I'm not quite clear on the update to your post.

Comment: @AlanH Could you please mention what is `subA`?  If it is `subA <- c(1,3)`.  It subsets the 1st and 3rd row.  But, if `subA <- c('a1', 'a3')`, we need to create a logical condition by `df1[df1$A %in% subA, c('A', 'C')]`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91238/discussion-between-alanh-and-akrun).

Comment: I just realized it's not giving me the output I expected because my subset, while a true subset, contains values that in columns not in the subset. In other words, my subset has values `x1, x2, x3`, but those values are the only values that are possible for any cell in the *entire* column. so it's returning me the entire column. I think I would need the indices corresponding to the subset, but those indices have to correspond to the original column's indices, instead of being re-indexed. I'm not sure if that's the right way to think about it though.

Comment: @AlanH Sorry, I didn't understand the problem.  If the `subA <- c('x1', 'x2', 'x3')` and the original 'A' column has none of those, it will return 0 rows.

Comment: @AlanH Can you update your post with a new example and expected output.  Perhaps you need `match`.